# InfluenceAnalysis of metagen object in R

Tags: r

I have come here after spending many hours on this problem hoping for some help. I am doing a metaanalysis in R in order to pool HR (hazard ratio) and I have been following a specific handbook for that (https://bookdown.org/MathiasHarrer/Doing_Meta_Analysis_in_R/).

After pooling HR using metagen I moved on to InfluenceAnalysis (using this function https://github.com/MathiasHarrer/dmetar/blob/master/R/influence.analysis.R) as per https://bookdown.org/MathiasHarrer/Doing_Meta_Analysis_in_R/heterogeneity.html; however, using

```
plot(m.gen.inf, "baujat")
plot(m.gen.inf, "influence")
```

the R always returns the same error: "Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :
'x' and 'y' lengths differ".

It seems there is a problem in the "InfluenceAnalysis" function itself; however, I am far too lame to identify and solve it. I will be greatful for any help.

Thank You so much.

Comment: You should have provided minimal reproducible code. What is the shape of m.gen.inf?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem together with Bravedistribution (thanks). You should not use the function InlufenceAnalysis provided by the link I shared; however, the one provided by dmeta package.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).